# HTML select tag in SWI-Prolog

Tags: php, html, prolog

How can i convert this to SWI-Prolog ? i didn't find on the internet how to write the select in prolog, and can you tell me how can i make the php code work in the ?

```
<select id="data_nastere_zi" name="data_nastere_zi">                
    <option value="ZZ">ZZ</option>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++){ ?>
         <option <?php print ($data[0][2]==$i)?'selected':''; ?>
         value="<?php echo $i;?>">
         <?php echo $i; ?>  </option>
         <?php 
         }
         ?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work the expected way:

```
?- phrase(html(select([id(data_nastere_zi)], 
                      [option(greetings),
                       option([selected],pythagoras)])), X), 
   print_html(X).
```

Produces:

```
<select id="data_nastere_zi">
<option>greetings</option>
<option selected>pythagoras</option>
</select>
```

You can use the neat modularization technique to generate the options you need:

```
my_options(0) --> [].
my_options(N) --> html(option(N)), { succ(N0, N) }, my_options(N0).
```

Then in the query, using `\` to refer to that rule:

```
?- phrase(html(select([id(data_nastere_zi)], 
                      [option(greetings),
                       \my_options(4)           % <-- note the \
                      ])), X), 
   print_html(X).
```

Produces:

```
<select id="data_nastere_zi">
<option>greetings</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>1</option>
</select>
```

You will need to add to this some information about which one you expect to be the selected one but it won't be difficult.